# Jest fails to parse an HTML file

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I have created an Angular project using `ng new my-project`. Now, I want to replace Jasmine and Karma with Jest. To do so, I have installed the following npm dependencies:

```
"jest": "^29.7.0",
"jest-preset-angular": "^13.1.2",
"@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
"ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
"ts-node": "^10.9.1",
"@angular-builders/jest": "^13.0.4",
```

So, apparently the default Angular version that is created with `ng` at the moment is 13.2.0.

I have uninstalled the Jasmine and Karma dependencies, added a setup-jest.ts file with the sole content `import "jest-preset-angular";` and a jest.config.js with the following content to my root directory:

```
module.exports = {
  preset: "jest-preset-angular",
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts"],
  globalSetup: "jest-preset-angular/global-setup",
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(ts|js)$": "jest-preset-angular"
  },
  testEnvironmentOptions: {
    url: "http://localhost"
  },
  testMatch: ["**/+(*.)+(spec).ts"],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "@app/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/app/$1"
  }
};
```

Now, for some reason, when running "jest" in my console, the only test that I have so far (app.component.spec.ts) is executed and fails with the error message hinting that Jest is trying to parse the app.component.html file. The message suggests to change the transformKey in my jest.config.js such that it doesn't match my html file. So I deleted the html part from the transformkey, but the test keeps failing. I have already tried deleting the jest-cache, but this doesn't help.

Could it be that I am missing some important configurations? In my tsconfig.json file, I specify the module as es2020, for example, but in my jest.config.js I am using commonjs module notation, am I not? The tsconfig.spec.json is configured in the following way:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jest"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Well, does anyone spot a mistake I am doing?

Comment: Excerpt from my **jest.config.js**: `moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'html', 'js', 'json', 'mjs'], transform: { '^.+\\.(ts|js|mjs|html|svg)$': [ 'jest-preset-angular', { tsconfig: '<rootDir>/src/tsconfig.spec.json', stringifyContentPathRegex: '\\.html$', useESM: true, diagnostics: {
ignoreCodes: [151001] }, isolatedModules: true } ] }`
See if it helps